# DynamoDB Mapper: allowed dataypes in swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

DynamoDB has following datatypes

Scalar types – Number, String, Binary, Boolean, and Null.
Document types – List and Map.
Set types – String Set, Number Set, and Binary Set.

what are the corresponding swift datatypes to each of these dynamoDB datatypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the DynamoDB `Number` type, it seems you need to use an `NSNumber`.

I had to figure this out the hard way: [Swift DynamoDB Mapper Sending Empty Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493204/swift-dynamodb-mapper-sending-empty-values/46503317#46503317)